# Is it possible to add a custom error page to an AngularJs 1.X application that is using Web API?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, webapi

I have an AngularJs application that uses Web API to  communicating with a WCF service on the back-end.  The requirements are to add a custom error page (web.config settings).  The user is to be re-directed to this custom error page whenever an exception occurs in the server code (i.e. C# code).  I am not sure this makes sense for a single page application.  However, if anyone has done this please help.

Answer (score 0):

You would leave this up to the SPA, not configure this in your Web.config

If your Web API gives you an internal error 5xx you display an error page.

Comment: Where would I put the code to check for the 5xx error?

Comment: In the service that calls your Web API. Any non 2xx will already be returned in the error callback of the promise. You will just need to check if the response.statusCode is between 500 and 599.

Comment: I believe I am using toastr to do that.  I think I should be looking down-stream from the Web API like at the WCF and below ...

Comment: I am hoping there is a way to do this with some configuration and a few liens of code.  I am hesitant to write exception handling code for this in each controller class ...

Comment: You should not do it in the controller. This is NOT what I suggested. Do it in ONE of the following: your proxy service, in a httpIntercepter, or configure the behavior in the httpProvider.